# OID Claim is missing in ASP Core ADB2C application

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, claims, objectid

I have a working ASP.NET Core ADB2C application, it uses custom policies, and configured to authenticate both local (ADB2C) and Google accounts.

I've recently noticed that the OID claim is missing from the token

```
public Task OnTokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
{
    _onTokenValidated?.Invoke(context);
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var claims = context.SecurityToken.Claims;
```

[image]

**Question**

The OID claim was definitely there when I used User Flows. Now I am using custom policies, based on [github's active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/SocialAndLocalAccounts/](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts)

I know there is a lot of stuff with input and output claims, and transformations, but I am really beginner in custom policy to diagnose what is missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that default custom policy, SignUpOrSignin.xml contains this:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
```

That means the object id is in the "sub" claim.
If you do want the oid claim, you can in addition add that like this:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
```

Comment: B2C custom policies are pretty advanced :) Requires you to configure a lot of stuff by hand

Comment: I meant, why a sample/educational material intentionally rename object id to *sub*, instead of oid, objectid, or http://..../objectid...

Comment: "sub" is the OpenID Connect standard identifier for the caller :) It has to be included. Object id is an Azure AD specific thing. Feel free to open an issue in their GitHub repository though :)